# Remove default margin of a slider

Tags: flutter

So it seems the material slider has default margin of 16 on both sides. How can I remove it? I tried looking at the source code but I can’t find where the margin was added

Answer (score -1):

Add you own margin. It would override the original.
[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49369950/flutter-layout-container-margin)

Comment: The slider widget doesn't have a margin setting